How to create a dictionary with distinct values from pandas dataframe?
I have a dataframe which looks like this:



col_a
col_b




a
1


a
2


b
1


b
2


b
3


b
4


c
1


c
2


c
3



I want to create a dictionary which looks like this (distinct/unique value for every key):
{a:1, b:2, c:3} or {a:2, b:4, c:1} or {a:2, b:1, c:3}, etc.
But with standard df.set_index('col_a')['col_b'].to_dict() I get:
{a:3, b:3, c:3}.
Is there a way to create a dictionary with unique values for every key? Or is there a way to filter dataframe to do the same?

It is unclear what you want. Are you expecting a Dictionary with a random choice from col_a or what?

I want a dict with 3 keys from col_a: a,b,c with in pair with a unique value each from col_b. If that is not possible, I want a df of shape(3,2) with unique combinations of values in col_a and col_b.

So to further clarify, the goal is for each of the values selected from col_b to be unique within the generated dict? So {a:1,b:2,c:3} is acceptable but {a:1,b:1,c:2} is not because a and b have the same value?

Yes, precisely. 'a' can be 1 or 2, 'b' - 1,2,3,4, 'c' - 1,2,3.  But if 'a' is 1,'b' and 'c' cannot be 1. All values must be unique.

If your input is not trivially always aaabbbccc 123123123, then please update your example to provide a more challenging input and highlight potential edge cases

@frogseer I see you're trying to accept multiple answers, be aware that you can only pick one answer ;)

Can you also comment on the real-life use case? How many unique values do you have in each column?

all ordered combination
Starting from the trivial case. If you have all combinations, as in your example, then you'll need to pick the 1st a, 2nd b, 3rd c, etc.
import numpy as np

N = 3 # number of items per group
a = np.arange(N)

out = df.iloc[a+N*a].set_index('col_a')['col_b'].to_dict()
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

generic approach
If you want a generic approach that will be independent of the combinations and order, you could compute a crosstab and perform a linear_sum_assignment:
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

tmp = pd.crosstab(df['col_a'], df['col_b'])
r, c = linear_sum_assignment(tmp, maximize=True)

out = dict(zip(tmp.index[r], tmp.columns[c]))

Output: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
This will ensure unique use of col_a and col_b.
Intermediates:
# tmp
col_b  1  2  3
col_a         
a      1  1  1
b      1  1  1
c      1  1  1

more complex example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'],
                   'col_b': [1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})

Intermediate tmp:
col_b  1  2  3  4
col_a            
a      1  0  1  0
b      1  1  1  1
c      1  1  0  0
d      0  0  1  0

Output:
{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}


Using a variation of Cartesian product of a dictionary of lists, this generates all of the valid dicts, based on the criteria. From here, you can select one by some mechanism of your choosing.
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# Build a DataFrame
data = {'col_a': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
        'col_b': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the DataFrame to a dict with the col_b values associated with each col_a value
values = {x: df[df.col_a==x].col_b.tolist() for x in df.col_a.unique()}

# Generate the Cartesian product of the possible values
full_list = [(dict(zip(values.keys(), val))) for val in itertools.product(*values.values())]

# Filter down to just the results that don't have any duplicate values
valid_list = [ x for x in full_list if len(set(x.values())) == len(x.values())]

I'm probably stuffing too much into a single line of code, but the idea here is to create a dict with a list of valid values from each col_a value, then generate a list with the cartesian product of all of those valid values, then use set() to get the unique values in each result to see if they are unique (if not unique, then the length of the set will be less than the length of the list of values).

That's a working approach, but it won't scale well. one you start having more than a tens of items, this will stop running in a decent time

You can easily convert a DataFrame to a dictionary by extracting unique values from each column with unique().tolist(), and then pairing them into a dictionary using dict(zip(unique_keys, unique_values)).
code:
import pandas as pd

# Just recreate the DataFrame
data = {'col_a': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 'col_b': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert the DataFrame to a dictionary
unique_keys = df['col_a'].unique().tolist()
unique_values = df['col_b'].unique().tolist()
result_dict = dict(zip(unique_keys, unique_values)) # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}


Thank you for the answer - it made me understand that I made a poor example: values in col_b can differ.

Your question gives me a feeling that you are not sure about the difference between list, tuple and dictionary. Let me remind you that a dictionary is a collection of key-value pairs, where each key is unique and associated with a value. Since your database has one-to-many mapping, dictionary is not a suitable option here because it not only disallows duplicate but also overwrites when it finds one.
You can define both columns as a separate lists and then merge them using the append/extend/+ method. Their positions can be easily manageable in this case as there is no issue like overwriting/uniqueness in tuples.
